# Open folder in dock by simply clicking

Tags: finder, macos, dock, alias

[image: my dock]

Hi. In my workspace I have these frequently used folders that I keep in my dock, but I find it annoying that I have to right click and click "open" every time i want to open them. Is there some way I can click the folders and it just opens?

I know that making an alias does the trick but I also like to drag files right into the folder on the dock and an alias doesnt let you do that.

Or does someone else have some creative idea to do both. Thanks. Im working on El-capitan.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: Thanks! (I can't tell if you're a bot though)

Comment: He is not a bot, he's one of the moderators. Click on his name to see who he is.

Comment: @mikeshinoda, I have rolled back your edit of adding "(solved)" and "EDIT: SOLVED!" to remove them as that is not how we do things here. Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and marking my answer as the accepted answer, as that will show it's solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can press the <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> key and click the target **Folder** in the **Dock**, this will open the folder in a new **Finder** window.

If the <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> key and click doesn't open directly to the target **Folder**, you can also try pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd> keys and click the target **Folder** in the **Dock**, this should open directly to the folder in a new **Finder** window.

You can also instead of *right-click*, just *click* the target **Folder** and select **Open in Finder**.

Comment: Command clicking the folder actually open the the folder above the target for me... I want to open the exact folder.

Comment: @mikeshinoda, I've updated my answer, please try pressing _option+command_  keys and click the target Folder.

Comment: @mikeshinoda accepting this answer, or a better one if you get one, means that the system classes the question as complete and won’t keep bringing it up for attention. It does not mean it is lost, people will still find it...